# How to delete n-th element of array with morphia

Tags: list, updates, morphia

For example i have a document

```
{
_id: 1, 
list:[
    {
      key: "a",
      "value":"ssss"
     },
    {
      key: "b",
      "value":"ssss"
     },
     {
      key: "c",
      "value":"ssss"
     },
]
}
```

and i need remove element with "c" key from the list.

With mongo console command i make like this and remove correct key

```
db.test.update({{_id: 1},{"$pull" : {"list" : { "key" : "c"}}},false,false)
```

there is a way to do it with morphia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [UpdateOperations.removeAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://bit.ly/1bpHnhC)  I think that'll get you what you need.

Comment: i have try somnthing like this: UpdateOperations<T> updateOp=new UpdateOperations.removeAll("list.key","c").  But it dont work for me. the element is not remove from array

Comment: try `UpdateOperations<T> updateOp=new UpdateOperations.removeAll("list", new BasicDBObject("key", "c")`